# Change amount of values in AmChart

Tags: javascript, csv, amcharts

I am making a graph using amchart. It gets the data from a csv file and puts it in a line graph. The thing I am trying to do is to change the amount of values is shows in the graph. For example, I would like to only show the last 30 values of the csv file. These are my Amchart settings:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart(htmlID, {
            "type": "serial",
            "color": "#FFFFFF",
            "theme": "light",
            "titles": [{
                "text": graphTitle,
                "alpha": 1,
                "color": "#FFFFFF"
            }],
            "dataProvider": data,
            "valueAxes": [{
                "title": xTitle,
                "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "gridAlpha": 0.3,
                "dashLength": 0
            }],
            "gridAboveGraphs": true,
            "startDuration": 1,
            "graphs": [{
                "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
                "fillAlphas": 0,
                "lineAlpha": 1,
                "type": graphType,
                "bullet": "round",
                "valueField": xField
            }],
            "chartCursor": {
                "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "zoomable": true
            },
            "categoryField": yField,
            "categoryAxis": {
                "title": yTitle,
                "autoGridCount": false,
                "gridCount": 20,
                "gridPosition": "start",
                "gridAlpha": 0,
                "tickPosition": "start",
                "tickLength": 20,
                "labelRotation": 290
            }
        });

    });
```

This is de parseCSV function:

```
        function parseCSV(data) {
        //replace UNIX new lines
        data = data.replace(/rn/g, "n");
        //replace MAC new lines
        data = data.replace(/r/g, "n");
        //split into rows
        var rows = data.split("n");

        // loop through all rows
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            // this line helps to skip empty rows
            if (rows[i]) {
                // our columns are separated by comma
                var column = rows[i].split(",");

                var category = column[yLocation];
                // second item is value of the second column
                var value = column[xLocation];

                // create object which contains all these items:
                var dataObject = {
                    //Or change this to field names! Like STN and TEMP
                    ID: category,
                    TEMP: value
                };
                // add object to chartData array
                chartData.push(dataObject);
            }
        }
        chart.validateData();
    }
```

I've tried to change the for loop so it only reads the last 30 lines. I don't know why, but somehow this doesn't work.
The question is thus how I change the amount of values for the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method to slice the CSV array to the last 30 values before assigning them to the chart:

```
function parseCSV(data) {
  //replace UNIX new lines
  data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
  //replace MAC new lines
  data = data.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
  //split into rows
  var rows = data.split("\n");

  //get the last 30
  if (rows.length > 30) {
    rows = rows.slice(rows.length - 31);
  }

  // loop through all rows
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    // this line helps to skip empty rows
    if (rows[i]) {
      // our columns are separated by comma
      var column = rows[i].split(",");

      var category = column[yLocation];
      // second item is value of the second column
      var value = column[xLocation];

      // create object which contains all these items:
      var dataObject = {
        //Or change this to field names! Like STN and TEMP
        ID: category,
        TEMP: value
      };
      // add object to chartData array
      chartData.push(dataObject);
    }
  }
  chart.validateData();
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/3de235f7a31017cbd1e740244bbea73d?editors=0010) using your code.

Comment: thank you for your comment! The problem still exists. I think there is a different problem.  Here is a snippet of the csv file.







`STN,"DATE","TIME","TEMP","DEWP","STP","SLP","VISIB","WDSP","PRCP","SNDP","FRSHTT","CLDC","WNDDIR"
969330,2017-02-07,10:13:34,28.9,27.2,1002.1,1009.5,14.6,12.5,0.01,0.0,010000,68.6,291
963230,2017-02-07,10:13:34,30.1,26.5,1034.0,1013.3,17.0,6.8,0.02,0.0,010000,50.3,106
968810,2017-02-07,10:13:34,29.7,26.4,1007.1,1007.8,12.5,7.7,0.00,0.0,000000,12.5,65`

Comment: Can you fork and modify the codepen I provided and reproduce the problem you're having? It's hard to tell what your problem is without seeing it for myself.

Comment: Well, I don't really know how to use that codepen website. But the thing is that I did not change anything in the code that is pasted in the question. Everything you see there is what I have. The imgur [photo](http://imgur.com/a/PUuI3) is what I get when I run the website. 
I also don't understand why the slicing would work, but changing the for loop does not work.

Comment: You didn't show how you changed your for loop in your question so I can't tell you why that didn't work for you. If jsfiddle is easier for you to modify, [here's a jsfiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/ehp0ajL6/) of the code I provided.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get it working. This is what I got so far: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tns5bqu6/4/). I hope that this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're trying to do. You're using the dataLoader's load/parse methods like [this knowledge base example](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-data-loader-functions-load-chart-csv-data/), correct? Rather than modifying the parseCSV function, just slice the result from the AmCharts.parseCSV call. After assigning the result to your data variable, set it equal to the slice call similar to my code above i.e. `data = data.slice(data.length - 31);`.